# how to add a date stamp to a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have created a bash script that will create a log of users logged in, disk usage and processes. I have everything working fine but the one problem I am having is when the log file is created there should be a date stamp in the name of the file. any suggestions? thanks

```
#code to create the date stamped log file
2) mkdir -p $HOME/log_Dir
   read -p "enter the name of the log file: " log_dir
   touch $HOME/log_Dir/$log_dir
   who > $HOME/log_dir/$log_dir
   du >> $HOME/log_dir/$log_dir
   ps -aux >> $HOME/log_dir/$log_dir
   echo "the log file has been successfully created" 
    ;;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below code gets the current timestamp and attach the date to logfile name.

```
    dateTime=$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S)        
    read -p "enter the name of the log file: " log_dir
    log_dir="$log_dir$dateTime.log"
    mkdir -p $HOME/log_Dir       
    touch $HOME/log_Dir/$log_dir
    who > $HOME/log_dir/$log_dir
    du >> $HOME/log_dir/$log_dir
    ps -aux >> $HOME/log_dir/$log_dir
    echo "the log file has been successfully created" 
    ;;
```

Comment: Quote the expansions! `IFS= read -r -p ...` so that you don't mangle backslashes and leading spaces. Before submitting an answer, it might be a good idea to run it through [shellcheck,net](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Define the date stamp function then call it as necessary

```
timestamp() {
  date +"%T"
}
```

The `%T` adds the current time. Refer to this for all the possible formatting options: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Time-conversion-specifiers.html#Time-conversion-specifiers